# Using Law of Total Probability for Conditioning Twice

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm given $X|λ$, which is an exponential random variable with parameter $λ$, and that $λ|p$ is geometric with parameter $p$, where $p$ is uniform between $0$ and $1$.

I know that the density function of $X$ with param $λ$ is $λe^{-λx}$,

and the density function of $λ$ with param $p$ is $(1-p)^{λ-1}p$

I'm trying to find the pdf for $X$ using the Law of Total Probability, but I'm just having troubles putting the given information together.
I have this setup but I think it's wrong

$f(X) = f(X|λ)f(λ) + f(X|\bar{λ})f(\bar{λ})$

Can I have some guidance on this please?

Comment: What is $\overline\lambda$?

Comment: I followed this $P(A)=P(A|B)P(B)+P(A|B^c)P(B^c)$. Tbh I'm pretty sure my set up is wrong :( @Math1000

Comment: @PTN that is only for events, the version for random variables is to sum(or integrate) over the supported values for the second variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that $$\begin{align}f_{X\mid \lambda}(x\mid y) &= y\mathrm e^{-xy}~\mathbf 1_{x\in\Bbb R^+}&&{\text{a probability density function}\\\text{ (exponential distribution)}}\\[1ex]f_{\lambda\mid p}(y\mid z)&=z(1-z)^{y-1}~ \mathbf 1_{y\in\Bbb Z^+}&&{\text{a probability mass function}\\\text{ (geometric distribution)}}\\[1ex]f_p(z)&= \mathbf 1_{p\in[0;1]}&&{\text{a probability density function}\\\text{ (continuous uniform distribution)}}\end{align}$$

The application of the Laws for Total Probability Measures is:

$$\begin{align}f_X(x)&=\sum_{y}\int_\Bbb R f_{X\mid \lambda}(x\mid y)~f_{\lambda\mid p}(y\mid z)~f_p(z)~\mathsf d z\\[2ex]&=\sum_{y=1}^\infty\int_0^1\mathbf 1_{0\leqslant x}~ yz(1-z)^{y-1}~\mathrm e^{-xy}~\mathsf d x\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you ver much for the answer. I just have a question (this is me being new to stat as well) is that what are those $\mathbf 1$ symbols?

Comment: Indicator functions.  They equal one when the indicated condition is true, and $0$ when it is not. $$\mathbf 1_{x\in A}=\begin{cases}1&:& x\in A\\0&:&\text{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$

Comment: I see . Thank you so much for the detailed answer!

Comment: I have a quick follow up if you don't mind
If I want to find $E[X]$, would it then be $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_{X\mid \lambda}(x\mid y)~f_{\lambda\mid p}(y\mid z)~f_p(z)~\mathsf dxdydz$ ?

Comment: Yes.  Well...$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\sum_{y}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty~ x~ f_{X\mid \lambda}(x\mid y)~f_{\lambda\mid p}(y\mid z)~f_p(z)~\mathsf d x\right)\right)\mathsf d z$$